# Retrieving a CacheManager object in EHCache

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, ehcache

I am using Hibernate v3.2.5 and EHCache (`ehcache-1.2.3.jar`) for second-level caching.

This is the **ehcache.xml** file:

```
<ehcache>
  <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="200" />
  <cache name="departments" maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="5" timeToLiveSeconds="200" />
</ehcache>
```

Below is the code I used for retrieving the `CacheManager`:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("trial.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    Dept department = (Dept)session.load(Dept.class, 1);
    //Performing some operations

    //Trying to get an instance of CacheManager
    CacheManager cm = new CacheManager("src/ehcache.xml");
```

I am getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.detectAndFixDiskStorePathConflict(CacheManager.java:269)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:252)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:196)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:131)
at com.demo.Test.main(OneToMany.java:52)
```

Again, I tried this as an alternative:

```
Cache cache = CacheManager.getInstance().getCache("departments");
```

But again I got the same exception.

**EDIT:**

**trial.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXX</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXX</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">XXX</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>    
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Kindly let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: there is no `src` folder in compiled package, replace `"src/ehcache.xml"` to `ehcache.xml`, also check if the xml is placed in the 'bin' or the folder that the class are compiled

Comment: If I change as you mentioned, then I am getting this exception: `Exception in thread "main" net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from ehcache.xml. Initial cause was ehcache.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: ok, did some research on this... and the NPE error is because another cache session was already started, maybe you have configured hibernate to use cache, if you can please post the trial.cfg.xml file

Comment: I have posted it in the above post. Kindly let me know on this.

Comment: change to false the property `<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>` and also remove `<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>`

Comment: If I do that, then the second level cache won't be used right? The idea is to clear all the second level cache data, hence I want to get an instance of `CacheManager` so that I can invoke the `clearAll` method. Kindly suggest.

Comment: yes, it wont be used... i think that there is one conflict as you are setting up both

Comment: Ok leave this scenatio and let me know how to clear all the data present in the second-level cache at a go? `CacheManager.clearAll()` is an option, how to use it then without disabling the second level caching so that no conflict is there?

Comment: not sure... but maybe this can help you: http://balamaci.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/multiplecachemanager/